# Android: Setting Button Margin and Button Width Depending Screen Density

Tags: android, button, margin, screen-resolution

I have a device with the following features:

Resolution: 1080 x 1920 
Density: 480 dpi (xxhdpi)    
Screen size: normal 
Scaled Density: 3.0

I've created a bitmap which has 960x1440 resolution. The bitmap has a rectangle which size is 795x150 px and it's positions are X:150 px and Y:900 px on bitmap.

I put the bitmap in drawable-xxhdpi folder.

My xml code in layout folder is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/loginscreen" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="265dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/login_button_left_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/login_button_top_margin" />

</LinearLayout
```

My dimes.xml file in values folder like this:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
    <dimen name="login_button_top_margin">300dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="login_button_left_margin">50dp</dimen>

</resources>
```

Bacause of my device's screen size is normal I just used layout and values folders for trial. I had hoped that the button will overlap the rectangle which is on the bitmap. But button stands above from the rectangle and size of the button is'nt equal to size of rectangle. dp values are supposed to be multiplyed by 3?

Answer (score 0):

create another folder under res folder name with layout-large and copy layout folder files(.xml) into layout-large folder and change code into layout-large

```
android:layout_width="68dp"
            android:layout_height="68dp"
```

android automatically its take large size in largetab small phone it's takevalues from layout folder